# How can I remove / delete a picturebox during runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding a basic game. The player collects a gem by touching it; this adds +1 to his score. The gem is a picturebox, and I want to dispose of it once it is collected.

As far as I know, this isn't possible, but there might be a hacky solution. Here is my code - I will keep researching and looking into this in the mean time. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it!

```
if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(gem.Bounds))
{
    points += 1;
    points_lbl.Text = points.ToString();
}
```

This works. However, the gem stays on-screen - so the player gets infinite points.

I have tried gem.Dispose(); but this merely 'hides' the picturebox, so collision is in effect still. gem = null; crashes the game. No XNA please.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6):

It's very possible, and it's not a hack.

Hide the control via `gem.Hide()` or by removing it from the parent form's control collection (`form.Controls.Remove(gem)`).

However, note that since it sounds like you added the picture box to the form via the designer, the `gem` instance variable will still refer to the control even though it's hidden or no longer in the form's control hierarchy. So your tests for the player collision will still pass, because the test is just mathematical and doesn't care if the form is visible/attached to the form.

So you will also want to check for that in your collision checks (if `gem.Visible` for example, or by nulling out the instance when you remove it and checking if `gem != null` before doing further collision tests).

Don't call `Dispose()` unless you really never want to use that instance again.